# How to construct an ItemEvent for use with dispatchEvent()?

Tags: java, events

I want to send a event to a `JComboBox` that can change it's selection.

I have this code:

```
JComboBox jComboBox = new JComboBox();
jComboBox.addItem("1");
jComboBox.addItem("2");
ItemEvent itemEvent = new ItemEvent(jComboBox, ItemEvent.ITEM_STATE_CHANGED, "2", ItemEvent.SELECTED);
jComboBox.dispatchEvent(itemEvent);
```

but it doesn't work.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Swing, but I suspect events are not used to update properties. When the selection changes the `JComboBox` fires an event in response, not the other way around.

Comment: A `JComboBox` doesn't _respond to_ `ItemEvent`s by changing its selection; rather, it  **sends out** `ItemEvent`s to inform others that a selection change has occurred.  Just call `jComboBox.setSelectedItem("2")` to change the selection programmatically (and when you do, an `ItemEvent` or two will be sent to any `ItemListener`s you have registered on `jComboBox`)

Comment: And what is `ItemEvent` for? Does not work like `KeyEvent`  or `ActionEvent` where you can fire the events?

Comment: As mentioned, an `ItemEvent` is fired in response to the selection changing; its purpose is to allow one to observe selection changes.

Comment: Yes, but how can I use the `ItemEvent` constructor and the `dispatchEvent()` method for the `JComboBox`?

Comment: How do you use all that _for what_? It's been explained that what you're trying to do in your question is wrong. If you're trying to do something else now then please [edit] your question; try to include a [mre] demonstrating the problem you're having.